# How to configure non-persistent Ignite to prevent swapping?

Tags: java, ignite

With my JBoss 7.1.6 EAP deployment with `-Xmx8g` with physical RAM on the VM set to 12 GB. I have a log message that appears when I am initializing my Apache Ignite caches:

> stdout:71 - [08:54:52] Nodes started on local machine require more
> than 80% of physical RAM what can lead to significant slowdown due to
> swapping (please decrease JVM heap size, data region size or
> checkpoint buffer size) [required=10662MB, available=11834MB]

I am using Ignite completely programmatically, and I am not using persistence. Here is my code:

```
System.setProperty("IGNITE_UPDATE_NOTIFIER", "false");

igniteConfiguration = new IgniteConfiguration();

int failureDetectionTimeout = Integer.parseInt(getProperty("IGNITE_TCP_DISCOVERY_FAILURE_DETECTION_TIMEOUT", "60000"));

igniteConfiguration.setFailureDetectionTimeout(failureDetectionTimeout);

String igniteVmIps = getProperty("IGNITE_VM_IPS");
List<String> addresses = Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1:47500");
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(igniteVmIps)) {
    addresses = Arrays.asList(igniteVmIps.split(","));
}

int networkTimeout = Integer.parseInt(getProperty("IGNITE_TCP_DISCOVERY_NETWORK_TIMEOUT", "60000"));
boolean failureDetectionTimeoutEnabled = Boolean.parseBoolean(getProperty("IGNITE_TCP_DISCOVERY_FAILURE_DETECTION_TIMEOUT_ENABLED", "true"));

int tcpDiscoveryLocalPort = Integer.parseInt(getProperty("IGNITE_TCP_DISCOVERY_LOCAL_PORT", "47500"));
int tcpDiscoveryLocalPortRange = Integer.parseInt(getProperty("IGNITE_TCP_DISCOVERY_LOCAL_PORT_RANGE", "0"));

TcpDiscoverySpi tcpDiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
tcpDiscoverySpi.setLocalPort(tcpDiscoveryLocalPort);
tcpDiscoverySpi.setLocalPortRange(tcpDiscoveryLocalPortRange);
tcpDiscoverySpi.setNetworkTimeout(networkTimeout);
tcpDiscoverySpi.failureDetectionTimeoutEnabled(failureDetectionTimeoutEnabled);
TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();
ipFinder.setAddresses(addresses);
tcpDiscoverySpi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);

igniteConfiguration.setDiscoverySpi(tcpDiscoverySpi);

Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(igniteConfiguration);

ignite.cluster().active(true);

// later, initialize my caches
String cacheName = cacheEnum.name();
CacheConfiguration<String, byte[]> cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>(cacheName);
int maxSize = Integer.parseInt(StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(
        PropertyHelper.lookupProperty(String.format(CACHE_SETTING_FORMAT, cacheName, ObjectCacheConstants.SETTING_MAX_SIZE)),
        String.valueOf(ObjectCacheConstants.SETTING_MAX_SIZE_DEFAULT)));
long expiresAfterMs = Long.parseLong(StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(
        PropertyHelper.lookupProperty(String.format(CACHE_SETTING_FORMAT, cacheName, ObjectCacheConstants.SETTING_EXPIRES_MS)),
        String.valueOf(ObjectCacheConstants.SETTING_EXPIRES_MS_DEFAULT)));

cacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
cacheCfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);
cacheCfg.setBackups(1);

cacheCfg.setOnheapCacheEnabled(true);
cacheCfg.setEvictionPolicyFactory(new LruEvictionPolicyFactory<String, byte[]>(maxSize));

Optional<CreatedExpiryPolicy> expiryPolicy = Optional.empty();
if (expiresAfterMs > 0) {
    expiryPolicy = Optional.of(new CreatedExpiryPolicy(new Duration(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, expiresAfterMs)));
}
```

I have googled around for this warning, but everything I find for solutions involves updating the persistence settings, but I am not using persistence.

In my case, without caching we can operate at 2GB heap no problem. So I am leaving 6GB for caching, and that should be more than enough. I would like to set it up so that my JVM uses up to 6G of ram and no more.

What fields should I look at changing in order to get the proper ram utilization for my program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an heuristic in Ignite that 4GB or 20% of available memory should not be occupied by a node to prevent OS from starting to swap memory operated by the Ignite node. Of course, it entirely depends on your OS settings. The entire amount required by a node is calculated as a sum of heap and off-heap memory. Heap memory is basically your JVM `Xmx` setting minus some GC overhead. Off-heap is a sum of all the [data region](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/memory-configuration/data-regions#configuring-data-regions) sizes along with their checkpoint buffer sizes (if one has a persistence enabled for a region). I suppose in your case it's just a [default](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/memory-configuration/data-regions#configuring-default-data-region) region without persistence, so it's 0 for the checkpoint buffer. By default it's 20% of available memory or at least 256Mb for the default region itself. You have some options here:

- Just ignore in case you're absolutely sure about your OS swappiness settings and you don't have any consuming software running on the same machine.
- Increase OS memory.
- Tweak `Xmx` to become smaller.
- Decrease default region (it's not recommended in fact but still an option) without turning a persistence on for the region.
- Combine some of above.